# Como desabilitar o cache do Opera 33 para que ele não faça cache dos scripts js?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Estou tendo muitos problemas porque além de estar aprendendo a programar, tenho o Opera fazendo cache de todos os `javascripts` me atrapalhando muito porque cada função nova que coloco no arquivo, é preciso dar **F5** no script pra carregar a nova versão do mesmo.

**Pergunta:** Alguém tem ideia de como desabilitar o cache de arquivos no Opera ou tem uma solução alternativa para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não se trata de cache, pois o navegador não tem consciência da modificação do arquivo.

Se você quer que o navegador atualize a cada alteração no arquivo, monte um setup com ferramentas do tipo do livereload com Grunt. Como você está começando a aprender, fazer o setup dessas ferramentas pode lhe tomar um pouco de tempo, mas é bem simples e um investimento de tempo necessário caso queria continuar a mexer com javascript, e uma massiva quantidade de tutoriais estão disponíveis, [como este por exemplo](http://tableless.com.br/grunt-voce-deveria-estar-usando/).

Se não tem interesse em se aprofundar nisso agora, pode utilizar sites como o [JS bin](http://jsbin.com/), onde a cada edição do seu código, o painel de resultados atualiza automaticamente. Também existem alternativas como o [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) e [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Guilherme, estou aplicando estas funções em um projeto que envolve HTML/CSS/PHP/AJAX e a única coisa que eu preciso é que ele recarregue a página com os scripts atualizados. Não posso perder tempo nesse projeto. Não sei como fazer com que o novo script seja carregado a cada vez que acesso a página.

Comment: Então você precisa utilizar ou o [livereload desktop](http://livereload.com/) ou a versão com [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reloading) ou [Gulp](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload). Recomendo o Grunt por ser mais amigável para iniciantes e conter mais material ensinando como utilizá-lo. Na própria página de cada um dos plugins há um manual básico de como começar a utilizá-los. Não conheço outra maneira que não seja utilizando livereload, mas creio que seja a única disponível no momento.